# iPhone 4s armv7 video quality is quite poor in webrtc ios

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo

I have testing for iPhone6 with `Webrtc` works well.

But 4s Video Streaming is very poor quality. Same  time video can freeze then Slow Working but not proper show.

How I can faster Video streaming With 4S.

Comment: This is too broad without seeing much more specific information.

Comment: we have pass 640*480 video height width and 30fps for generate video stream. we have check same paramatere in ios 6 it's working but when we test on ios4 then video stream freez some time.

Comment: you won't get 640x480 @ 30fps out of the 4s. Reduce either resolution or framerate or both.